# MapDirectionsRenderer in @angular/google-maps

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular-google-maps

```
"@angular/animations": "^11.2.14"
"@angular/common": "^11.2.14",
"@angular/compiler": "^11.2.14",
"@angular/core": "^11.2.14",
"@angular/forms": "^11.2.14",
"@angular/google-maps": "^11.2.13"
```

I'm not seeing MapDirectionsRenderer in the node_modules and notice that [this commit](https://github.com/angular/components/commit/9dbf49b6609f5d31dacf25c40d5e7133b23e0f50#diff-2ef3837eb38ef71c88b9cdda67974b2efc4869e68def795ccdd838a2ad4f2b89) has 12.1.1 as the version number.  So I assume that this means that @angular/google-maps v 11.2.13 doesn't have the MapDirectionsRenderer at all.

Does this mean that I either have to upgrade angular to 12 or implement directly with [Google maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple#maps_directions_simple-typescript)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded to Angular 12 and MapDirectionsService is now present and available.  So that's the answer.